# What should be in the POM file for Neo4j?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, neo4j, pom.xml

I cannot seem to get the import (import org.neo4j.driver.v1.*;) to be recognized. It cannot resolve neo4j.

I believe it has to do with my pom.xml file which I am completely unsure of how to set up.

Right now I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    </build>


</project>
```

This is not fully working as well. It was before, but I messed with it a little to much. If anyone can help me get on the right track it would be much appreciated!

Comment: the `dependency` element should be in a `dependencies` section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `<dependencies></dependencies>` tag. And a couple of description tags too.

Pick the version you want to use here: https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=neo4j

And add it to your `pom.xml`

It should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId> // You're Missing this
<artifactId>demo</artifactId> // You're Missing this
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> // You're Missing this
<packaging>jar</packaging> // You're Missing this

<name>demo</name> // You're Missing this
<description>Demo project</description> // You're Missing this

<dependencies> // You're Missing this
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> // You're Missing this

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
</build>
```

Comment: Alright this seems to make it work. I am still having trouble resolving the import. I don't know why though I have to jar in the lib and everything. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Try re-vamping your `pom.xml` sometimes you forget something in the midst of the code. Create a new Maven project using an IDE and add your dependecies one by one and see if the IDE doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Maybe you want to use this link to get the dependency: [Neo4J JDBC](https://maven-repository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-jdbc) or use this link to browse through the results: [Neo4J Results](https://maven-repository.com/search?q=neo4j)

Answer (score 1):

From the Maven global repo:

```
<project>
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0-M01</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j.driver/neo4j-java-driver

Comment: Is that not what I have?

Comment: You need to put the <dependency> nested inside of <dependencies>.